# How old is the Nostromo?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

The ship has obviously seen some wear and tear by the time the events of Alien take place and, based on [Why Are Synthetics in Alien So Advanced?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118428/why-are-synthetics-in-alien-so-advanced/119488#119488) even the technology that built the Nostromo is significantly older than modern tech.

My question is, roughly how old is the Nostromo or the make/model of that particular ship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the factbook ['Alien: The Weyland-Yutani Report'](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien:_The_Weyland-Yutani_Report), the USCSS Nostromo was constructed in 2101. It was destroyed 21 years later (by Ellen Ripley) in the year 2122.

[image]

For the record, the second date is subject to [some controversy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/when-in-which-year-is-alien-set)

Comment: Nice, simple answer. Thanks for that. Not sure why Google failed me so bad there.

Comment: I this instance, the answer was on the wiki but I had to dig around for the sources to make sure they were accurate. I don't believe it until I've seen it with my own eyes.